# Установка приложения

Tags: android

Создал .apk файл через простую `Export Unsigned Application package`. При установке выдает "Приложение не установлено". Какие варианты ошибки тут? Как можно исправить?

Сначала проект был для 4.0.3, потом конвертировал в 2.1. Может что-то не так сделал?

Comment: А как конвертировали? Уверены, что ничего специфического из 4.х (или вообще из 2.2+) не использовано?

Comment: Посмотрите, какая версия sdk  в манифесте стоит

Comment: в этом та и проблема вначале ступил потом уже было поздно опомниться

Comment: 7-ая версия

Comment: А это приложение уже установлено на телефон.
У меня такое было,надо было на устройстве удалить и тогда работало.
Я исправил.что-то в манифесте и всё заработало.

Answer (score 2):

проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь установить на телефон неподписанное приложение. поэтому оно и не устанавливается. из документации:

> The important points to understand about signing Android applications are:
>
> All applications must be signed. The system will not install an application on an emulator or a device if it is not signed.

чтобы подписать апк файл [почитайте](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

тут же возникает вопрос, а почему тогда при отладке приложение устанавливается на телефон?
ответ: потому что при отладке оно подписывается специальным отладочным ключем